# JPA entity is not persisted with my extra field

Tags: java, jpa

```
class Extra {
    int a;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "data_table")
@Data
class Data {
    @Column int state;
    @Column(name = "extra") String _extra;

    @Transient Extra extra;

    @PostLoad
    void preLoad() {
        extra = mapper.readValue(_extra, Extra.class);
    }

    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    void prePersist() {
        _extra = mapper.writeValueAsString(extra);
    }
}

Data data = jpaRepository.findOne(...);
data.setState(1);
data.getExtra().setA(1);
jpaRepository.save(data);
```

I want to use extra string column as Extra object.
So I made @PostLoad, @PrePersist callbacks, which are converting extra column.
But, when I persist data object, state value is persisted, but extra column (Data._extra) is not persisted. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Why not use a converter on the Extra mapping instead of making it transient?  The converter would convert it to/from a string instead of relying on the preLoad and prePersist methods, and allow you to remove the _extra field.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Convert.html

Comment: Currently, I'm using converter. Now I'm just wondering why extra column is not persisted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your save method - is it using merge?  Since Extra is transient, it is invisible to JPA and would not be merged into the managed instance.  So it will be null when the preUpdate method is called.  you'll have to write your own save method to merge in transient values if you need them.

Answer (score 3):

Your defined extra object is `@Transient`. Transient objects aren't saved to DB.

Comment: Sorry, I meant extra column. (_extra member of Data)

Answer (score 1):

If you really meant to ask about extra.a then the answer of @Abdullah G if right.

But if you made a typo then you probably meant `_extra` field.

Hibernate caches the value just being persisted so you're getting a cached old object in @PreUpdate callback.

**UPDATE** The solution I've found is to use

```
@Column(name = "password", insertable = false, updatable = false)
```

instead of `@Transient` annotation. However, it creates a column in the database that is always null.

---

Comment: I couldn't understand. Do you mean that extra in prePersist() is old object? But I set extra with data.getExtra().setA(1). How could it be..?

Comment: @chaeyk data object itself is old. you can even see it in a debugger. I've found this issue and checked myself. when you view the `extra` field the second time, it is not changed while the `state` is. so before call to dataRepository.save(data) I see the `extra` field is changed but when I debug in @PreUpdate - it is not